# Elastic collisions between blocks

Tags: code-golf, pi, physics

The 3Blue1Brown Youtube channel released a video a year ago called "[Why do colliding blocks compute pi?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jsYwFizhncE)" which describes a model where a block `A` of mass \$a\$ slides into a block `B` of mass \$b\$, which then pushes block `B` into a wall, causing it to bounce off the wall and then collide again with block `A`.

The miracle of this process is that if \$a/b = 10^{2n-2}\$ the number of total collisions (both between `A` and `B` and between `B` with the wall) is given by the first \$n\$ digits of \$\pi\$.

---

## Example output

```
+-------+---+--------+
| a     | b | output |
+-------+---+--------+
| 1     | 1 | 3      |
| 2     | 1 | 5      |
| 3     | 1 | 5      |
| 4     | 1 | 6      |
| 5     | 1 | 7      |
| 10    | 3 | 6      |
| 7     | 2 | 6      |
| 9     | 2 | 7      |
| 1     | 2 | 3      |
| 1     | 5 | 2      |
| 100   | 1 | 31     |
| 10000 | 1 | 314    |
+-------+---+--------+
```

(These values were calculated using [this web applet](https://editor.p5js.org/KyleCow/full/SJbg0W6z4) from Reddit user [KyleCow1](https://www.reddit.com/r/3Blue1Brown/comments/agpnl3/i_made_the_collisions_demo_in_p5_js/). Please let me know if I've made any mistakes.)

---

## Challenge

Your challenge is to take two positive integers \$a, b \in \mathbb N_{>0}\$, and output the number of collisions in this scenario. Your program should be able to handle all \$a, b \leq 10\,000\$. This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge, so the shortest program wins.

Comment: can we input b,a instead of a,b?

Comment: ..or a+ib as a complex number?

Comment: Sure, either of these inputs is fine.

Comment: @ngn in what way would the complex number help?

Comment: @RGS if your language has a concise way of getting the argument of a complex number (the "theta"), then arctg(b/a) could be theta(a+ib), but i'm not sure it would help much in this case, as b/a is under a sqrt

Comment: The case where `b=1` is now on the OEIS as [A331859](https://oeis.org/A331859).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Jelly, <s>10</s> 9 bytes

My first Jelly submission :')

```
÷½ÆṬØP÷Ċ’
```

*-1 byte* thanks to Mr.Xcoder

Uses the formula as in the video. Receives the input flipped; OP gave permission. It probably has room for further golfing, so be sure to give me feedback!

```
÷½        divide b by a and take square root
  ÆṬ      take the ArcTan of that; then
      ÷   divide
    ØP    pi
          by the number we had.
       Ċ  Round up
        ’ and subtract one
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///w9kN7D7c93Lnm8IyAw9uPdD1qmPn///9oQx0FZGSso2AEQ6YQwViQIiMdYx0THVMdQwMdcx1LHUMQNDAAYQODWAA)

Comment: [9 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///w9kN7D7c93Lnm8IyAw9uPdD1qmPn///9oQx0FZGSso2AEQ6YQwViQIiMdYx0THVMdQwMdcx1LHUMQNDAAYQODWAA). This gives a different result for the pair `3,1->5` (test case #3), but the current 10-byter wrongly gives `6` due to floating point inaccuracies, so it's actually a "fix" too :)

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 12):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>18</s> 16 bytes

```apl
¯1+⌈○÷¯3○.5*⍨⎕÷⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v8/7VHbhOpD6w21H/V0PJrefXj7ofXGQFrPVOtR74pHvVsPb3/Uu6v2//8QkDog/1HnoiIg81FXc5o@UMZKPS0xM0cdyALKFT3qblHPz1av5TJUAAFDhRAFYy4jONuUyxiJbQJnm3GZwtnmXIYGILYxWNwcLG4EZlvC2eZQ843A5kPYpkC2EVCvAcxeQxAHyIVwTAA)

rendered as the equivalent `{¯1+⌈○÷¯3○.5*⍨⍵÷⍺}` in the tio link, to facilitate testing; `⎕` means evaluated input; `⍺` and `⍵` are the arguments to an anonymous function

$$\left\lceil\frac\pi{\textrm{arctg}\sqrt\frac ba}\right\rceil-1$$

(that's the formula from [the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jsYwFizhncE). i recommend watching it. it's well explained and the animations are great for building intuition.)

Comment: You could [go Extended](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/P@1R24TqQ@sNtR/1dDya3n14@6H1xkD6UcesR71bD29/1Lur9v//EJAiIP9R56IiIPNRV3OaPlDGSj0tMTNHHcgCyhU96m5Rz89Wr@UyVAABQ4UQBWMuIzjblMsYiW0CZ5txmcLZ5lyGBiC2MVjcHCxuBGZbwtnmUPONwOZD2KZAthFQrwHMXkMQB8iFcEwA "APL (Dyalog Extended) – Try It Online") for `.5*⍨` → `√`

Answer (score 9):

## JavaScript (ES7),  <s>41</s>  39 bytes

Takes input as `(a)(b)`.

```javascript
a=>b=>3.14159265/Math.atan((b/a)**.5)|0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fdBLDoIwFAXQuavosCWx/0IYwA5cxAPBT0hrpHHk3quRCf3EOz25Ly/3Di9Yx@ft4Y/WnacwdwG6fuh6RYUWppW1YSfwVwoeLMYDA1JV1JA3D6Ozq1smurgLnrFA3xAsCEGMIXWIVUZqElV/VUdaJ2oibRIV/Keq3G22rixrG2l2OVJVVrOpzL7i@61EzpzvWIcP)

#### How?

Instead of using a *ceil* function and subtracting \$1\$, we deliberately use a slightly underestimated approximation of \$\pi\$ and *floor* the result with a bitwise OR.

For \$a,b\le 10000\$, it was empirically proven to give the same results as this safer 44-byte version:

```javascript
with(Math)f=a=>b=>ceil(PI/atan((b/a)**.5))-1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fdBBDoIwEAXQvadgOUMCbSmVuIC9CxOvMCAIhFAjjR6/GtnQlvi3L38y@SO9aGmew8Mks7611r4H08OFTI9dSWVVl1XTDhNcz4wMzQA1I4zjVCEmwjZ6XvTUppO@Qwci@gZBIEaMRfLgauao8lT@1dzRo6fK0cJTwX8q97vF2s329eRocNlRua9q1Sz4im@3EiFzvuHcfgA)

Comment: I'm assuming you tried reducing the number of decimal places in your pi approximation? I'm quite sad because 355/113 is a really nice approximation of pi and would allow you to golf even more.

Comment: @RGS That's correct. Going from memory here, but I think I need either 3.14159264 or 3.14159265.

Comment: The simplest fraction in that range is 99378/31633, which isn't short enough to golf, unfortunately

Answer (score 5):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 32 bytes

```hs
a#b=ceiling(pi/atan(sqrt$b/a))-1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bdBRC8IgEAfw932Kg/ag4NicW6MH@yLVwy2kJGdr2uc3cRRMEl/8ecefuzu6hzImBNyN8qq00fZGZl2jR0vca/HlWCOlFQ9eOe9AwolwBvEKygr4HtIm6zcm/liXbL@xPtmwMd7EhLxwYNDmdkiWNScTucWcNgtp1lF4zr@Pjl6KYkJt4@Tzoq2HEtAYIGeCDEYGz7enUB0h7g@kXJ9pVeED)

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, <s>30</s> 29 bytes, 25 characters

```
⌈Pi/ArcTan@Sqrt[#2/#]⌉-1&
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7/1FPR0CmvmNRckhinkNwYVFJtLKRvrJh7KOeTl1Dtf9p0YY6hrEK@voKAUWZeSVcadFGaHxjNL4JGt8UjW9ooGOMImCuY4TCt0TjG2LwTdEMNMCwwgBV7D8A)

*-1 byte* thanks to ExpiredData

Uses the formula explained in the video.

Comment: You can just use `#` instead of `#1`

Comment: @ExpiredData thanks :D

Answer (score 4):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>49</s> 43 bytes

```ruby
->a,b{(-1.arg/((a*b)**0.5+b.i).arg).ceil-1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc7BjoIwFAXQvV9xUzaApVIQzZigq1nNwoQtYdEizpiY0aAsDPTbmUeJzSRNm3N7@9K206/xnI/RXnHd@5EUqv1e@b4KdRCGsciWWlyCKQxE3VyukTRjuQBKyUErrfiExCKbkf7H2mIzI7PYzpAxPXdXW47E4cPi3bNIHWhI8p4Qz5@Qzi5ZU1SJRtU/ON0wKA7NceueAxVb5DiXU1SR7t3zAeb1lOZTAwew4xfDDuyzKI4FMxjg9cpw2rVBvqezNfC9ntomYIvm9zT@AQ)

-5 thans to G B, nicely done

-1 replacing `1i*b` with `b.i`

Comment: I suppose it would be acceptable to take floats as input so that `->a,b{(Math::PI/Math.atan((b/a)**0.5)).ceil-1}` works -- but you may want to ask the OP.

Comment: You can use `-1.arg` for `Math::PI`

Comment: And `((a*b)**0.5+1i*b).arg` is the same as `Math.atan(b**0.5/a**0.5)`

Answer (score 4):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>63</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>47</s></sup> 46 bytes

```c
f(a,b){a=ceil(acos(-1)/atan(sqrt(b*1./a)))-1;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVFta4MwEP7eX3EIQmLj1Fo7inNfxn7FlBFj7GRWOxOYTPzrc/EVLQuX43LPPU8uF2ZeGOu6FFES44YGjGc5oqwUyHSwRSUtkPiqJIoN58GiGGPT8dsuKyRcaVYgDM0O1OoTkgv5Tt8iCKBxCBwIuASOBDwCjk3gkcBZRaPZ9uBsu/W3/Hjhr80d5EbzxuSKyOsbZ5InI9UdSpSdhjtPczBquL2ac5zYrCyEBPZBK0N5zj55NYpoYf16COvzi9qeRmB9drWJnZYVoL6BrEh4rWi2P4VPILIfXqZobg1bU8JYMj7s90P1PMP5OVQpTbMc8MjfwPEMx//CQsH9b0KMtwBXwDKpe@atUiUp0vSEgJ6A@dx7XYSFenuvRUCQZUIiCHg0qbe7tvtlaU4vojO/OzO//gE)

*Saved <s>11</s> 12 bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)!!!*

Uses the formula from the video as [ngn](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/24908/ngn) recommended.

Answer (score 4):

## Excel, 35 <s>37</s> bytes

-2 bytes thanks to @Chronocidal

```
=CEILING(PI()/(ATAN((B1/A1)^.5)),1)-1
```

Comment: You seem to have an unnecessary set of brackets around `ATAN`, for 35 bytes

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 30 bytes

```
/t©ažq;‚Δ{ÐO;Å¼®‹èsO;‚}нžqs/î<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fv@TQysSj@wqtHzXMOjel@vAEf@vDrYf2HFr3qGHn4RXF/iDx2gt7gSqK9Q@vs/n/39AACLgMAQ)

Almost definitely golfable..

Implements the formula but because 05AB1E doesn't have arctan we have to calculate it, this does it by bisection.

---

## Explanation

```
/t                                - sqrt(a/b)
  ©                               - store this value
   ažq;‚                          - the array [0, pi/2] 
        Δ                         - repeat until the array passed in does not change
         {Ð                       - sort then triplicate array 
           O;Å¼                   - arctan of the average of the array (bisection)
               ®‹                 - is this greater than the sqrt(a/b)? 0 if so 1 if not
                 èsO;‚            - Take the index from the current two guesses and combine with their average
                      }н          - Stop looping and get the first value
                                  - (this should be close enough to arctan(sqrt(a/b))
                        žqs/      - push pi then divide it by the atan(sqrt(a/b)) guess
                            î<    - ceil and decrement
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 59 bytes

```rust
|a:f64,b:f64|(f64::acos(-1.)/(b/a).sqrt().atan()).ceil()-1.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZBNboMwEEb3OcUXFpEtuRB@kqignKCLHgChykRGQqKmwc6KcHZqOxRCNrWsGfvNzJPl7qb0WEl881oSin4DsxqhUeE83nlaHRNW2ngnJqQpv7SKvIU@DUgZcOqra6cJ9bnmZpz6F1E3hJr6aD3ZZtZpobTCGbkjQB4ymB0X7A9EDhwWEL@CxIHjAg4OnBYQ7o1y1XJiiFbg3YHnGQfiFTDi6Nm6fzw2XLGZJhMuMpdcqNoOu5wzlAztTReoJXaPT@gnB8CVEp3@EtctqQg3V9jvRjmdqBudsddK8BT9YDps8hisn2azLwhelLbsJP9NDy7@dLXUjdwS7/PDM5Vh/AU)

Answer (score 3):

## J, 19 bytes

```
_1+1p1>.@%_3 o.2%:%
```

Try in Jconsole as the TIO seems to be quite weird.

Usage: `f=:_1+1p1>.@%_3 o.2%:%`

## Example

`f 10000` => `314`

Comment: This is not a valid answer because it is not a syntactically valid function by itself. A function should be either a train `_1+1p1>.@%_3 o.2%:%` or an explicit definition `{{_1+>.1p1%_3&o.%:1%y}}`. [TIO example showing a train.](https://tio.run/##y/r/P83WKt5Q27DA0E7PQTXeWCFfz0jVShUormBoAAQA)

Comment: @Bubbler changed to a train

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 55 bytes

```python
lambda a,b:ceil(pi/atan((b/a)**.5)-1)
from math import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fdDfCoIwFAbwe5/iQDebrHSuJQk9iXkxK3Hg/jB209MvjaSp1Ln98X18HPv0vdEsdJdrGIRq7wIEaavbQw7Iykx4oRFqM4HT9MDxnuKkc0aBEr4HqaxxPg2dcVMIpIa6poQ2BN63A5ZAdHURG18a@2PH2E5L47GVS6M5YR/c5EpS/Ow8x7bujI2tjX@tWG/J56Vjjm5w5gmPozYVWCe1Rx0af4txeAE)

Answer (score 2):

## AWK, <s>56</s> 55 bytes

```
{x=atan2(0,-1)/atan2(($2/$1)^.5,1);$0=int(x);$0-=$0~x}1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JclBCoAgFATQvadw4UJB839NIsKrBC4jcCUkRF3dvrZ4zDCTrrO1u8ZUUnYStEFl/y6FswLVPgWNahMQj1xk7c1EAW99sDXkyBzxZCaBIHDPFu7YSnAINMK4oOcH)

I know I can save a few bytes by hardcoding Pi to some arbitrary precision, but I'm not sure how accurate it is outside of the provided test cases.

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 46 bytes

```php
<?=ceil(pi()/atan(($argv[2]/$argv[1])**.5))-1;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hdLNCoMwDADgu08RZIdWpm2qRZz7eYQ9wPQgIlMQJ875@p1O2GEj9hYSviSE9HVvzPFyKqumZX3DuCjGomNsVwz36aZysQaYc88LNOc@pqYq6we4WZd117GuBpiK9lU9D0vCTR1nLeMeABD8M7gBg9/2KPDbEHjgfuQKlQUqCoYWGFIwssCIgtoCNQVRzjKkYChQUjJeRipKKhFTMLHAhNzVAnETagrqDSjn82y9jvw/jzFzVkqDbw)

Not very original I guess, applying the formula from the video..